# Is Conversion between DataStream and Table supported for Python API

Tags: apache-flink, pyflink

Is Conversion between DataStream and Table supported for Python API in the latest stable version V1.13.2?

Answer (score 1):

Interoperability between the DataStream and Table API has been improved and addressed via FLIP-136, which will be released in Flink 1.14.0 and is not available in Flink 1.13.

Comment: Thanks Martijn. any idea when Flink 1.14.0 release is expected?

Comment: It should be there in the next couple of weeks

Comment: @saktheesh Flink 1.14 was released yesterday :)

Comment: Thanks Martijn! gonna explore the Interoperability between the DataStream and Table API